# Can't delete from two tables with a relation in an @Transaction

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have been using Spring 4's `UserDetailsManager` to create users, the schema is the one suggested by their docs for `USERS` and `AUTHORITIES` tables.

I have also been using the Spring Data `@Repository` annotated interfaces to manage data in a separate `REGISTRATIONS` table which is defined to have a relation on the `username` field in the `USERS` table.

The problem I've been facing is that when I wish to delete a user, I first  delete the record from the `REGISTRATIONS` table using the injected Spring Data repository, followed by a call to `deleteUser()` using the `UserDetailsManager`. (This is simply two consecutive calls in an `@Transactional` method in an `@Service` annotated class).

For example

```
registrationsRepository.delete(uuid);
userDetailsManager.deleteUser(registration.getUsername());
```

However, the deletion of the user fails as the record in the `REGISTRATIONS` table (1st line) has not been deleted. Subsequently I get an exception (2nd line) complaining about not being able to delete the user as there are foreign key constrains in the `REGISTRATIONS` table preventing it from being deleted.

If these updates happen in the same transaction, why does this fail?

EDIT:

```
@Repository
public interface RegistrationsRepository extends CrudRepository<Registration, UUID>
{
    // No EntityManager injected - uses Spring Data method queries
    // No additional methods defined
}
```

Registrations table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Registrations (
  username varchar(64) NOT NULL REFERENCES Users (username),
  uuid UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Comment: Try to flush the EntityManager after your first delete.

Comment: does the Registration entity have a reference to the User entity? or just some kind of id that map to the FK?

Comment: To complement Guillaume's suggestion: delete() doesn't delete the entity. It marks the entity for deletion. The actual SQL query deleting the row is only executed at flush time.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I've updated my question to give more info. I had considered that, but would mean I would have to separately inject the EM in to my service class and call `flush()` separately - it just didn't feel right. I'm also not sure if it would be the same one used by the transaction, as I have read the @Transactional can create a new EM from an EM factory and bind to the thread when the transaction begins.

Comment: @JensSchauder. I was looking at adding the @ManyToOne/@OneToMany annotations to my Registration entity, but then couldn't see that Spring's `User` 'entities' are defined as `@Entities`, so wasn't sure if I could do that. So just mapped to an Id in the `USERS` table (see edit above)

Comment: @JBNizet My SQL is a little rusty, and would have to try it, but if I executed  two plain old SQL statements on the DB directly, one which removed the 'registration' row, followed by one that removed the 'user' row, then I thought I could execute them as two separate statements in the same SQL commit/transaction. Does the same not apply in a JPA transaction? Do I have to do them in two separate commit/transactions?

Comment: That's why you should call flush(). Without flush, the deletion of the user row happens **after** the deletion of the registration row. Because delete() doesn't delete. It only marks the entity for deletion. flush() is what forces JPA to execute the delete SQL statement.

Comment: @JBNizet Ah! Think I understand. I thought all the actions would occur together in the correct order at the end of the transaction. I guess it's because Spring's `UserDetailsManager` does not have entities under control of an EntityManager, it uses JDBC directly to update the DB, whereas my entities were not being persisted until the EntityManager flushed them. Had everything been under the control of one EntityManager, it would have worked out the relationships and known that A needs to be deleted before B and occurred without an intermediary `flush()`? It's fixed now! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Yes, it would probably have worked out, provided there is indeed an association between the entities. If you just store the ID of another entity, JPA isn't aware that one references the other, and thus could choose the wrong order for the deletes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I understand it, Spring's `UserDetailsManager` uses JDBC calls to delete the 'users' and 'authorities' from the respective tables.

My 'registrations' entities were being managed by an `EntityManager` which had no defined relationship (at the ORM level) to the 'user' records. This relationship was specified purely at the DB level.

The `EntityManager` would mark the 'registration' entity to be deleted, while the `UserDetailsManager` would actually delete the 'user', which happens before the `EntityManager` has been flushed at the end of the transaction. This fails as the 'registration' entity hasn't yet been deleted, the transaction is still not complete, but the JDBC calls had already attempted to delete the 'user's and 'authorities'.

To fix this I did the following.

```
class DefaultService implements MyService {

    private final EntityManagerFactory emf;

    // Inject RegistrationRepository and UserDetailsManager...

    @Inject
    public DefaultService(EntityManagerFactory emf, ...) {
        // ...
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void serviceMethod(UUID uuid, String username) {
        registrationsRepository.delete(uuid);

        // Flush the entity manager to remove this record from the DB first.
        EntityManagerHolder entityManagerHolder = (EntityManagerHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(emf);
        entityManagerHolder.getEntityManager().flush();

        // These will be JDBC calls, 'users' are not managed entities
        userDetailsManager.deleteUser(username);
    }
}
```

I obtained the EntityManager in this way to ensure I get the correct one bound to this thread for this transaction. If this is overkill or there is a better way of doing this, please comment!

Hope that helps someone. And is correct!

Comment: The other correct way would be to create an Entity @OneToOne (or other) link between these tables so your ORM is aware of the relation. When it does its dirty check, it will detect the relation and flush the transaction automatically.

Comment: Ah - can I do that? Spring's `UserDetailsManager` didn't appear to treat the objects it returns as ORM entities. If I can do that, then that would be my preferred approach.

Comment: You can always declare a Class as an @Entity and use it in a transaction context, but that might be a little tricky for the UserDetailsManager (plus that's not really its purpose)